# "ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()" with string id

Tags: java, hibernate, in-memory-database

I got exception when I'm writing hibernate in memory test.

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():

```
@Entity
public Account{
     @Id
     String num;
}
```

First, this id of pojo is String and I cannot change it, I don't have access to DB and change pojo, all I can do is create in-memory tests.

Then, before I save this pojo, I filled every field in this pojo, still it throws this exception. And because of in-memory test, the in memory DB is empty, there're not conflict id there.

Any idea, what else can cause this exception?

Comment: Do you set a value to the `num` field as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add `@GeneratedValue` on top of the variable. If you don't, you need to give the id a value. Doesn't matter its in memory test or not.

Comment: Thank you, I thought @GeneratedValue just for Number type ids, clearly I'm wrong about that

Comment: @Walter If the answer solved your question you should start by accepting the answers. I noticed you asked a fair amount of questions but haven't accepted any single answer yet. Accept answers will encourage the user to answer you questions.

Comment: @OPK I'm still getting `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String`